# Poles and zeros from FRF

Tags: frequency-response, frequency-domain

How can I determine the poles and zeros of a system given its frequency Response?

I can understand how one can find the Frequency response from poles and zeros of a system. Is it possible to do it the other way round?

Comment: Do you also have phase information or just frequency-magnitude plot?

Comment: I have just the Frequency magnitude plot

Comment: The poles and zeros are not uniquely determined by the the magnitude of the frequency response.